# which ip address i have to use for packaging with eclipse in ROKU Developement?

Tags: roku

[Snapshot of Packaging with Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Lcs.png)
I tried with my local IP address but it gives error Unable to set Roku box to home Screen and sometimes it Gives Timeout Error even after I increase Timeout Seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have Developer Mode enabled. You can enable this by pressing :

Home Button x 3
Up x 2
Right
Left
Right
Left
Right

If you already have it enabled and it is still giving you issues connecting, try this.

Close the console in Eclipse. Restart your Roku. Go to Settings->System->System Restart->Restart or just unplug the darn thing and plug it back in. Once it has finished rebooting and is on the Home Screen, make sure it is connected to the internet. Then try connecting again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use local IP address of Your Roku device.
Go to Settings-->Network-->About and You will find Your device local IP address.
If You are having connectivity issues make sure that both Roku and You computer are in the same network. Connect them both to the network using LAN cable. If that does not help, set up Your computer IP address manually. 
I had similar issues using WiFi network.